# Finding the intersection and differences in data using R

Tags: r

I'm interested in getting the intersect between A and B and then find the elements that are in X and not C, and vice versa. I have the following codes:

```
A <- c("ret", "mu", "ty", "umh")
B <- c("ret","ty", "sem", "eel")
C <- c("ty", "uuh", "argh", "wwe")
X <- intersect(A,B)
U <- diff(C, X)
```

But I got some errors that I've not been able to understand:

```
Error in diff.default(C, X) : 
'lag' and 'differences' must be integers >= 1
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `?setdiff`

Comment: @Frank, the answer area is a little further south of the question :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Added an answer.  I felt strange about answering with such a short response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `setdiff` function.  `diff` is for differencing, see `?diff` for an explanation and some examples of its functionality, which should explain why it will not work with character vectors.